# How to install pywinauto in python 2.5.1

Tags: python, python-2.5, pywinauto

I am not able to install pywinauto in python 2.5.1

Version 2.5.1 don't have pip.
I tried to copy paste pywinauto from 2.7.1 but didn't work.

Comment: Well, maybe old pywinauto version could work on Py2.5. I've edited the answer about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [pywinauto documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pywinauto/0.5.4/)

> Installation
>
> **(Python 2.5 and before is not supported)**

So it's time to upgrade. Python 2.5 now belongs to retrocomputing.

Comment: This might be legacy requirement for old proprietary code to be extended a little bit. I'm not surprised, but generally agree with you.

Comment: Migrating from 2.5 to 2.7 isn't a big deal. The only issue is the python bindings (`.pyd` files)

Answer (score 0):

The latest pywinauto is not compatible with Python 2.5 because statements like `except Exception as exc:` won't work in Py2.5 (they are required for Py3.x compatibility and work for Py2.6+). Though you have chances with pywinauto==0.4.2 and before. 0.4.2 can be downloaded here (see "Releases" tab in the repo): https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/archive/0.4.2.zip

You need to unpack it and run `C:\python25\python.exe setup.py install`